# How works extensions method in VB.net with an interface as a object

Tags: vb.net, extension-methods

I am struggling with an extension method in VB.NET, but I can't find why I can't implement this (I came from C# and I still having issues like this between language specification and how the language works, sorry if this question is too newbie):

```
namespace FakeBusiness.BusinessInterface
{ 
    public interface IBusiness
    {
        int Id { get; set; }
        string Name { get; set; }
    }
}

namespace FakeBusiness.SharedExtensions
{
    using FakeBusiness.BusinessInterface;

    public static class ExtensionsMethods
    {
        public static bool IsEmpty(this IBusiness theObject)
        {
            return theObject != null && theObject.Id != 0;
        }
    }
}

namespace FakeBusiness.BusinessLogic
{
    using FakeBusiness.BusinessInterface;
    using FakeBusiness.SharedExtensions;

    public class Business : IBusiness
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public String Name { get; set; }
    }

    public static class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            IBusiness obj = new Business();
            Console.WriteLine($"The object is: {(obj.IsEmpty() ? "empty" : "not empty")}");
        }
    }
}
```

And I want to achieve the same logic but for a reason VB.NET says 'Cannot resolve the symbol' even if I import explicitly the namespace from the extension method:

```vb
Namespace FakeBusiness.SharedExtensions {
    <Extension()>
    Public Function IsBusinessObjectEmtpy(ByVal business As IBusiness) As Boolean
        Return (business IsNot Nothing AndAlso business.Id = 0)
    End Function
End Namespace

Namespace FakeBusiness.BusinessLogic

    Public Class BusinessObject : Implements IBusiness
        Property Id As Integer Implements  IBusiness.Id 
        Property Name As String Implements IBusiness.Name
        
        Public Sub New()
        End Sub
    End Class 
    
    Public Interface IBusiness
        Property Id As Integer
        Property Name As String
    End Interface

    Public Class FakeBusiness.SomeLogic

        Public Sub SomeLogic()
            Dim newObject = New BusinessObject()
            If newObject.IsBusinessObjectEmpty() Then
                ' Do something...
            End If
        End Sub

    End Class
End Namespace
```

Also I read that a possible solution is to use the instructions `Option Strict On/Off` and also `Option Infer On/Off`.
I tried every possible combination between these pair of compiler instructions but it didn't work.
Anyone knows how to fix this issue with an extension method?
Another possible solution is to put the same method into a base class and implement with an interface, but I want to achieve this in this way
because it will be useful to use in every class if I use a `TypeParameter` in the extension method.

Any suggestion?

Comment: Typo?  `Namespace FakeBusiness.SharedExtensions {`

Comment: You cannot have a function directly inside a namespace either. It must be in a module. And after you fix that, please notice that in C# the variable is defined as `IBusiness`, which is why the extension method can be found. You must do the same in VB, `Dim newObject As IBusiness = New BusinessObject()`.

Comment: Also, `Public Function IsBusinessObjectEmtpy` is misspelled.  `Public Class FakeBusiness.SomeLogic`  Don't think ".SomeLogic" belongs there.

Comment: Yeap, it was a typo LarsTech. I put the extension method like @GSerg said inside a Module and made the module Public and now it compiles. Thank you for the help. It was simplier that I thought

Comment: Also note that in C# you have `&& theObject.Id != 0`, in VB `AndAlso business.Id = 0`.

Answer (score 0):

In a Console Application project with a root namespace of `FakeBusiness`, the following is the direct equivalent of that C# code:

```vb
Namespace BusinessInterface

    Public Interface IBusiness

        Property Id As Integer
        Property Name As String

    End Interface

End Namespace
```

```vb
Imports System.Runtime.CompilerServices
Imports FakeBusiness.BusinessInterface

Namespace SharedExtensions

    Public Module ExtensionMethods

        <Extension>
        Public Function IsEmpty(theObject As IBusiness) As Boolean
            Return theObject IsNot Nothing AndAlso theObject.Id <> 0
        End Function

    End Module

End Namespace
```

```vb
Imports FakeBusiness.BusinessInterface
Imports FakeBusiness.SharedExtensions

Namespace BusinessLogic

    Public Class Business
        Implements IBusiness

        Public Property Id As Integer Implements IBusiness.Id
        Public Property Name As String Implements IBusiness.Name

    End Class

    Module Program

        Sub Main(args As String())
            Dim obj As IBusiness = New Business()
            Console.WriteLine($"The object is: {If(obj.IsEmpty(), "empty", "Not empty")}")
        End Sub

    End Module

End Namespace
```